# How to show dropdown dynamically from database in mediawiki?

Tags: mediawiki

I am using latest mediawiki(version - 1.32.0). My requirement is to show drop-down with dynamic value from database in form section with add and edit with form section.

I found some options related to SF Select with custom parser function to show dynamically values in drop-down, But I don't have any idea how to create,use and where custom parser functions.

Please share some code snippets with examples.

Thanks in advance.